# Scrolling png with text & alpha on top of a static UIImageView

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, uiimageview

I have a view controller that has a view structure as follows:

```
FilesOwner
FirstResponder
View
   ImageView (.jpg)
   ScrollView
     ImageView (.png)
```

The text in the innermost imageview has white text and clear (alpha) all around.  I want to scroll the innermost imageview, and see the background image (the .jpg) behind it.

Its not working.  Its acting like the scrollview background obscures the underneath .jpg. I say this because if I change the background color of the scrollview, that's what I see i.e. if I set it black, I see black behind my .png, if I set it white, I see white.  If I change the alpha of the scrollview that doesn't seem to work either.  The one other thing I tried was unchecking drawing: Opaque, but that doesn't get it either.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the alpha value of your scrollviews background color to 0 (not the alpha value of the scrollview itself). The scrollview should be set to not opaque.

(didn't try, just guessing...)

Comment: Setting the .png drawing to NOT opaque has it looking correct in IB, but when I run, I still can't see the background .jpg